# Whats design pattern does UITableView use to populate and what are the benefits of delegate and datasource setup?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

Whats design pattern does UITableView use to populate and what are the benefits?
Is it delegate pattern? Reason I am asking is that it's not just delegate but the datasource as well.Seems more like along the line with MVC.

I have just gone through a couple of tutorials online their\my code is working but it looks like I am missing the point.I end with all these methods in my main controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;//any number based on datasource size.
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//names is an array.
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

It is a view based application . Should it be in a sperate controller.Otherwise it just looks messy and over the top way of doing something simple. I am not at all saying Objective C or apple is wrong but just that I am a beginner and missing the whole point of this delegate and datasource setup.
so to summarise can someone please explain:

1-Whats the benefit of this delegate and datasource setup?
2-Whats the name of this design pattern?
3-Should I have a separate controller (in view based application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Apple's parlance, `delegate` implements call-back methods which modify the UI behavior, and `dataSource` provides the data. In a bigger app, you can use two different objects to be the delegate and the data source separately.
2. I'm not familiar with the official terminology, sorry ...
3. Depends on the size of your app. Even if you just use `appDelegate` for everything, it's recommended to add

   ```
    #pragma mark -- table view delegate methods
    ...methods...
    #pragma mark -- table view data source methods
    ...more methods...
   ```

   so that the method list is shown nicely inside Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for replying I just wanted to see how #pragma looks like and can find the functions list . Where can I see the result of adding this.

Comment: You have a list of methods in the upper edge of the source editor area. Click it and you see the list of methods, with `#pragma mark` added to it.

Comment: great did not even know about that . Thank s for help.

Answer (score 1):

Look into n-tier design methodologies.

Most all patterns are to create code thats adaptable to change (and less prone to bugs).

The benefit here is that with those pieces abstracted from your view controller will allow more flexibility and ideally less headaches for maintaining the code. If your requirements change, or your data you have to modify this file. Whereas with the data source isolated you could end up just having to modify that one file. More important with the data since it tends to be external and perhaps created by some other entity this is often changed. Also storage strategy may change, you could go from XML to core data with no impact on the view controller, delegate or views.

On the delegate, what if design changed and this same data was reused elsewhere. If the delegate isn't tied to this view controller this becomes a simple matter of reusing the delegate code where needed.

Then add other complicating factors, maybe you've subclassed `UITableView`. Perhaps, you display the same data in two different places, and in both cases you've subclassed `UITableViewCell`. Maybe the requirements aren't for two different views, but this view controller here has an option to display a detailed version and a brief version.

Food for thought.